# Superscript <sup> affecting table alignment

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-float, superscript

Why is a table-data element causing a misalignment of the previous row?

`<table>`

working as it should: http://jsfiddle.net/WH3uz/2

Not working with data: http://jsfiddle.net/NCs8H/

Comment: Hey @Andre i think you want to this http://jsfiddle.net/WH3uz/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used to

in your last `td` `<td colspan="3">`

=====

```
<table class="menu-item">
<tr>
    <td class="num">14.</td>
    <td class="fdname"> Greens</td>
    <td> <sup class="gf-vg"> GF / VG</sup></td>
    <td class="price">$4.75</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="3">Romaine lettuce, purple cabbage, pickled beets, and fresh cilantro, drizzled with our house vinaigrette.</td>
<tr>    
</table>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NCs8H/3/)**

**[Update Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WH3uz/3/)**

Comment: I ended up using a slight variation of the update demo where I still kept the price in it's own td cell (so I can set the margin between it and the name) however that is a working solution.  I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Every second `<td>` have the same width (it's the principe of a table), so the first line has the same width than the second...

A picture is worth a thousand words: http://jsfiddle.net/NCs8H/1/

To fix this, you can set `<td colspan="3">` to your `td` with data.

Comment: This is a working solution however the one above doesn't rely on setting a colspan.  Thank you!